# jQuery Countdown Each Second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a jQuery countdown type animation, that once it hits 0 it executes a function. However I'm having problems because I'm unsure how to go about doing this. I thought I'd do a while loop then pause for a second until it hits 0. However it doesn't seem possible to pause a while loop. So I'm wondering what's the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for the setInterval() js timing function?

Comment: may help (js): https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
var counter = 10;
var yourFunc = function(){}
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    counter--;
    if(counter <=0){ yourFunc(); clearInterval(interval); }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

- `countdown` takes an HTMLElement to display itself and the number of seconds to count down for
- It returns a Promise that resolves when the counter reaches 0
- We can use a `.then` call to apply a function when the count-down has completed

```js
function countdown(elem, s) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    function loop(s) {
      elem.innerHTML = s
      if (s === 0)
        resolve(elem)
      else
        setTimeout(loop, 1000, s - 1)
    }
    loop(s)
  })
}
                     
countdown(document.querySelector('#a'), 3).then(
  function(elem) { console.log('done', elem) }
)

countdown(document.querySelector('#b'), 5).then(
  function(elem) { console.log('done', elem) }
)

countdown(document.querySelector('#c'), 10).then(
  function(elem) { console.log('done', elem) }
)
```

```html
<p id="a"></p>
<p id="b"></p>
<p id="c"></p>
```

You should also be aware that `setTimeout` and `setInterval` do not guarantee that the *milliseconds* argument used is 100% accurate …

```js
var last = Date.now()
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  var now = Date.now()
  var delta = now - last
  console.log(delta)
  last = now
}, 1000)

setTimeout(clearInterval, 10000, interval)
// 1000
// 1003
// 998
// 1002
// 999
// 1007
// 1001
// ...
```

If you need a long running timer with high accuracy, I recommend you adapt the solution to use delta-based updates to the clock. If you rely upon `setTimeout` or `setInterval` for accuracy, you will be sad.

```js
function countdown(elem, ms) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    function loop(ms, last) {
      let now = Date.now()
      let delta = now - last
      if (ms <= 0) {
        elem.innerHTML = 0
        resolve(elem)
      }
      else {
        elem.innerHTML = (ms/1000).toFixed(3)
        setTimeout(loop, 25, ms - delta, now)
      }
    }
    loop(ms, Date.now())
  })
}
                     
countdown(document.querySelector('#a'), 3000).then(
  function(elem) { console.log('done', elem) }
)

countdown(document.querySelector('#b'), 5000).then(
  function(elem) { console.log('done', elem) }
)

countdown(document.querySelector('#c'), 10000).then(
  function(elem) { console.log('done', elem) }
)
```

```html
<p id="a"></p>
<p id="b"></p>
<p id="c"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive function

```
var countDown = function(secondsRemaining){
    secondsRemaining -= 1;
    if(secondsRemaining <= 0){
        //execute
    } else {
        //wait 1 second and call again
        setTimeout(function(){
            countDown(secondsRemaining);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

then to initially start countdown (5 seconds)

```
countDown(5000);
```

Comment: `once it hits 0 it executes a function`

Comment: hense why I put the comment `//execute` at line 4. Read more closely before down voting

Comment: Too overkill for such a simple task friend.

Comment: Reguardless, recursion is a good thing for OP to be familiar with

Comment: I think you're a little over confident that OP wouldn't prefer the flexibility this offers. The question is quite vague and this solution is far from complex.  How about we let OP decide..

Comment: @naomik no, but why would I rewrite a function that is already pre-built into javascript? Never re-invent the wheels fellas.

Comment: @zsawaf what function was rewritten that exists in JavaScript? That's terrible reasoning anyway. As strange as it may sound, many of the functions that exist in lodash perform better than the natives they're designed to replace.

Comment: @naomik This does EXACTLY what setInterval does.

Comment: again I ask you, what is the harm in teaching OP how to use recursion? Afterall, we are here to help teach people how to be better developers

Comment: @godmode Because it's rarely used in web development, and mostly used in AI, and because rewriting native functions is bad practise. Why? Because native functions are stable, tested, and run at optimal complexities in most cases.

Comment: @zsawaf this is not exactly what `setInterval` does. Without additional API calls, setInterval will loop indefinitely. `setTimeout` as godmode has used it here handles the termination much more elegantly.

Comment: @zsawaf *"[recursion] is rarely used in web development, and mostly used in AI"* lol. Just because you don't understand how to utilize recursion effectively doesn't mean other people don't regularly employ it to solve problems.

Comment: @zsawaf *"rewriting native functions is bad practise. Why? because native functions are stable, tested, and run at optimal complexities in most cases."* That's pretty far from true and the primary reason that libraries like jQuery, Underscore, and Lodash are so extremely popular. These libraries, whether you use them or not (I don't), resolve many **inconsistencies** that exist in native JavaScript across every browser/implementation

Comment: @naomik "Additional API calls" > one line > clearInterval > equivalent to break > close to no cost. Also, yeah because recursion is so hard xD set base case, call function again on a smaller input set, return output on base case. Because not everyone is taught that in first year of comp scie. ROCKET SCIENCE MAN! lol I'm done with you.

Comment: @zsawaf not to mention, `setTimeout` and `setInterval` don't work as advertised. The `delay` parameter fluctuates by a small amount. You have to use other means if you need more accuracy for long-running timers. See my answer for a solution that demonstrates how to work around that.

Comment: @zsawaf I don't even know how there's a debate. Your answer to the question doesn't even address the OP's actual needs. So what merit do you have here? Show us your no-wheels-reinvented solution so we can all be enlightened. Also, that's the second time you've used gender-exclusive language while speaking to me in this thread. I don't particularly care, but you should be aware that you're probably offending others.

Comment: @naomik I use "man" as a gender exclusive term. So apologies for offending you. Also no argument, you taught me something new with interval discrepancies. Upped your answer.

Comment: @zsawaf I already said I don't particularly care. But thank you for acknowledging it and remaining civil.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like the following :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var counter=10;
  countDown();

  function countDown(){

    $('#showNumber').text(counter--);
    if(counter>=0) 
      window.setTimeout(countDown,1000)
    else
      otherFunction();
  }

  function otherFunction(){
     $('#showNumber').text('FINISHED!');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It does not require jQuery.

```
var count = 5;  // Number of times to run 'counter_function'.

// Run 'counter_function' every second (1000ms = 1 second)
var counter = setInterval(function(){
    counter_function()
}, 1000);

// The function to run when 'count' hits 0.
var done_function = function() {
    console.log('done');
}

// The function to run at each interval.
var counter_function = function() {
    console.log('count');
    count--;

    if(count === 0){
        done_function();
        clearInterval(counter);
    }
}
```

It will print the word 'count' every second for 5 seconds, and at the last second it will also print 'done'.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something like this OP?

This executes every second. You can use clearInterval() just as I added in the comment section whenever you want it to stop.

```js
var start = 10; // time to countdown from in seconds
var interval = setInterval(
  function(){ 
    if (start == 0) {
      complete();
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    $(".update").html("<h4>Countdown "+start+"</h4>");
    start--;
  }, 1000);

function complete() {
  console.log("called the callback, value of start is: "+start);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="update">
  
</div>
```

Comment: It's supposed to countdown and call a user function when the timer reaches 0

Comment: @naomik So, set the time interval to whatever you want it to be, once the time hits 0, it executes, if he wants to exit out of the interval, I provided him with the code to do so.

Comment: so should the OP set `i` to a negative number since your answer always counts *up* ?