# How to Use Class Instead of ID

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I have this code from this question [How To Create Multiple CountDown Timers In The Same Page Using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57939173/how-to-create-multiple-countdown-timers-in-the-same-page-using-javascript#). I am not a JavaScript expert so if someone can help me to rewrite this code by using class instead of ID so that I can use multiple class.

This is the code

```
<div id="trip_2022-12-31"></div>
<div id="trip_2021-11-01 01:02:12"></div>
 <div id="trip_2024-01-01"></div>
 <div id="trip_2023-02-01"></div>
 <div id="trip_2023-01-04"></div>
   
    <script>
        function TimeRemaining(){
   var els = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="trip_"]');
   for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
     var el_id = els[i].getAttribute('id');
     var end_time = el_id.split('_')[1];
     var deadline = new Date(end_time);
     var now = new Date();
     var t = Math.floor(deadline.getTime() - now.getTime());
     var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     var hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))/(1000 * 60 * 60));
     var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
     var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
     if (t < 0) {
        document.getElementById("trip_" + end_time).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED';
     }else{
        document.getElementById("trip_" + end_time).innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s";
     }
   }
}

function StartTimeRemaining(){
    TimeRemaining();
    setInterval(function(){
        TimeRemaining();
    }, 1000)
}


StartTimeRemaining();
    </script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried replace them with class var els = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="trip_"]');
   for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
     var el_id = els[i].getAttribute('class');

Comment: @CoderBoy Add the code in the question.

Comment: OK sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code slightly. Try this:

```js
function TimeRemaining() {
  var els = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class^="trip_"]')];
  els.forEach(el => {
    var end_time = el.className.split("_")[1]
    var deadline = new Date(end_time);
    var now = new Date();
    var t = Math.floor(deadline.getTime() - now.getTime());
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    if (t < 0) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("trip_" + end_time)[0].innerText = 'EXPIRED';
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName("trip_" + end_time)[0].innerText = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s";
    }
  })
  window.requestAnimationFrame(TimeRemaining);
}

function StartTimeRemaining() {
  TimeRemaining();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(TimeRemaining);
}

StartTimeRemaining()
```

```html
<div class="trip_2022-12-31"></div>
<div class="trip_2021-11-01 01:02:12"></div>
<div class="trip_2024-01-01"></div>
<div class="trip_2023-02-01"></div>
<div class="trip_2023-01-04"></div><br>[Added to check expiration function]
<div class="trip_2021-2-17"></div>
```

Specifically, I shortened the `el_id` since it didn't have much of a purpose, and I put the whole thing in a `forEach`. I also changed the `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName(...)[0]`. I also changed the `innerHTML` to `innerText`, since `innerText` puts the text in as it is, and prevents problems with special characters. Finally, I changed the `setTimeout` to `requestAnimationFrame` since that typically calls as often as possible without hindering other functions. This was in order to show the timing as close to as the real thing as possible, since if the page loads at halfway through a second then the timer would be half a second off.

Comment: so you are using document.getElementsByClassName("trip_" + end_time)[0]. and for this it work only for the first one other ones are not working. It is same as Id.

Comment: This is the way I wanted, but I wanted multiple working class also. It is the answer of my question so thank you.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. For me it works for all of them, and all the timers are updating. BTW, I'm using Chrome. Could you let me know what you are using so I can troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="trip_2022-12-31"></div>
        <div class="trip_2021-11-01 01:02:12">
    </div>
         <div class="trip_2024-01-01"></div>
         <div class="trip_2023-02-01"></div>
         <div class="trip_2023-01-04"></div>
        
    <script>
function TimeRemaining() {
  var els = [...document.querySelectorAll('[class^="trip_"]')];
  els.map(el => {
    var end_time = el.className.split("_")[1]
    var deadline = new Date(end_time);
    var now = new Date();
    var t = Math.floor(deadline.getTime() - now.getTime());
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    if (t < 0) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("trip_" + end_time)[0].innerText = 'EXPIRED';
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName("trip_" + end_time)[0].innerText = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s";
    }
  })
  window.requestAnimationFrame(TimeRemaining);
}

function StartTimeRemaining() {
  TimeRemaining();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(TimeRemaining);
}

StartTimeRemaining()


</script>
```

it's work bro

Comment: OP used `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="trip_"]')`

Comment: yeah you can but instead id use class

Comment: I tried class instead of ID, but now it's showing nothing

Comment: Did you change the HTML to use class= as well?

Comment: It only works for the first one and the others are not showing.

Comment: see here https://codepen.io/talhaouycoding/pen/RwoXXpa

Comment: This is the same as @Endothermic_Dragon

Comment: yeah , i think so

Answer (score 0):

When you call `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="trip_"]');` you have a reference to the individual `DIV` elements so you do not to do any further calls to `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName` - simply use the reference from the nodelist.

I modified the HTML structure slightly as the use of className to hold the datetime info seems, to me, a poor choice. The `dataset` attribute was introduced to allow use of arbitrary data in situations such as this. This leaves the `class` free to be used for other, more suitable, purposes.

Using the `dataset` ideology leads nicely to extending this perhaps to include details of what the timer is actually for. The code below uses a `data-event` attribute to display that info when the timer completes ( or as a title when running )

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  /* Maintain a reference to each timer activated */
  let timers={};

  /* Time calculation constants */
  const yr=365.25;
  const min=1000 * 60;
  const hr=min * 60;
  const day=60 * 24;

  /* Find all the DIV elements that have `trip` data */
  document.querySelectorAll('div[data-trip]').forEach( ( div, i )=>{
    (function( trip ){

      timers[i]=NaN;

      (function(){
        /* calculate the delta between now and the date in question */
        let t=Math.floor( new Date( trip ).getTime() - new Date().getTime() );

        /* initialise the timer */
        timers[i]=setTimeout( arguments.callee, 1000 );

        /* perform the main time calculations */
        let obj={
          y:Math.floor( t / ( min * day * yr ) ),
          d:Math.floor( t / ( min * day ) ),
          h:Math.floor( ( t % ( min * day ) ) / hr ),
          m:Math.floor( ( t % hr ) / min ),
          s:Math.floor( ( t % min ) / 1000 )
        };


        /* Display the countdown */
        let output=['<span>'+obj.s+'</span>secs'];
        if( obj.m > 0 )output.unshift('<span>'+obj.m+'</span>mins');
        if( obj.h > 0 )output.unshift('<span>'+obj.h+'</span>hours');
        if( obj.y > 0 ){
          /* if the number of years is greater than zero - calculate remaining days */
          if( obj.d > 0 )output.unshift('<span>'+Math.ceil( obj.d - ( obj.y * yr ) )+'</span>days');
          output.unshift('<span>'+obj.y+'</span>yrs');
        }else{
          if( obj.d > 0 )output.unshift('<span>'+obj.d+'</span>days');
        }

        div.innerHTML=output.join(', ');
        div.title=div.dataset.event;


        /* display final message and cancel timer if expired */
        if( t <= 0 ){
          div.innerHTML=[ 'Expired', div.dataset.event ].join( ' - ' );
          div.className='expired';
          /* clear the timer */
          clearTimeout( timers[ i ] );
          delete timers[i];
        }
      })();
    })( div.dataset.trip );// assign the trip data/date as arg to the anonymous function
  });
});
```

```css
.expired{color:red}
div[data-trip]{font-family:monospace;font-size:1.1rem;margin:0.5rem auto;cursor:pointer;}
div[data-trip] span{font-weight:bold;color:green}
```

```html
<div data-trip='2021-03-22 12:30:00' data-event='Get Covid-19 vaccination'></div>
<div data-trip='2022-12-31' data-event='Go to Rouen'></div>
<div data-trip='2021-12-01 01:02:12' data-event='Skiing in Verbier'></div>
<div data-trip='2024-09-28' data-event='MX Des Nations'></div>
<div data-trip='2026-02-06' data-event='Winter Olympics 2026 in Cortina'></div>
<div data-trip='2023-01-04' data-event='World Spaghetti Day'></div>
<div data-trip='2021-03-22 08:30:00' data-event='Do important stuff'></div>
```